# Can't implement the cross_validation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, cross-validation, sklearn-pandas

I am a beginner in Python Machine Learning,I was practicing stock prediction program in python but according to tutorial "from sklearn import cross_validation" is used.But in my compiler Intellij IDEA i can't use it it show error

```
import quandl, math
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing, svm
from sklearn import cross_validation
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
df = quandl.get('NSE/RCOM', api_key='-pQJsBYvTAsU-cSopBvA')
df = df[['Open', 'High', 'Close', 'Low', 'Total Trade Quantity']]
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Close'] - df['Open']) / df['Open'] * 10
df = df[['Close', 'HL_pct', 'PCT_change', 'Total Trade Quantity']]
forecast_col = 'Close'
df.fillna(-99999, inplace=True)
forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.01 * len(df)))
print (forecast_out)
df['lable'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
X = np.array(df.drop(['lable'], 1))
y = np.array(df['lable'])
X = preprocessing.scale(X)
y = np.array(df['lable'])
print(len(X),len(y))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_valalidation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
clf = LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
accuracy = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print(accuracy)
```

}

```
OUTPUT:
C:\Users\aravind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
C:/Users/aravind/Desktop/programtopractics/untitled3/stock.py
C:\Users\aravind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages
\sklearn\externals\joblib\externals\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py:47: 
DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; 
C:/Users/aravind/Desktop/programtopractics/untitled3/stock.py
see the module's documentation for alternative uses
 import imp
31
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aravind/Desktop/programtopractics/untitled3/stock.py", 
line 29, in <module>
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_val_score.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'train_test_split'
3019 3019
```

Comment: cross_val_score is a function, you confused it with the cross_validation module.

Comment: Exactly where should I change !!

Comment: i just learn from this link-->https://pythonprogramming.net/forecasting-predicting-machine-learning-tutorial/ for your reference see the program in that link,I know the cross_validation is a function but how do implement it  " cannot import name 'cross_validation' from 'sklearn" in output

Comment: You might want to use this then: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `train_test_split` is in module `model_selection` and not in `cross_validation` anymore.

Thus, use

`from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split`

Also, replace this

`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_valalidation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)`

with

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
```